# Is there anything other than MythTV that lets me time stretch video?

Tags: linux, mythtv

With MythTV there is a setting so you can watch a recording up 1.5 times the normal rate.  It also adjusts the audio so everyone doesn't sound like Mickey Mouse (lowers the playback pitch).  Is there a program for Linux, besides MythTV, that does this?

Comment: But that's half the fun! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mplayer` has `-af scaletempo` which "scales audio tempo without altering pitch" according to the man page.

Comment: Note:  This requires a newer version of mplayer than what ships with Ubuntu Jaunty.  

SMPlayer provides a GUI that will let you scale the playback easily.

Answer (score 1):

VLC player will speed up the video and keep the pitch normal too.  VLC player is available on Linux, Windows, Mac, BeOS and Syllable.

VLC's website is [here](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, or does what you are asking about, but it is a popular alternative for MythTV, Freevo: http://freevo.sourceforge.net/.